# Stuck at Grub dual booting window/linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, external-hdd

Grub image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYkGe.jpg

I recently installed Linux Ubuntu on my external drive for dual booting, everything I touched was my external drive. I gave it 8Gb of swap partition and the rest for root. First time installed it worked perfectly, and boot fine.

But after the second boot it just stuck at Grub, I restart computer again and it booted fine, everything worked. But the third time forward it always stuck at grub, can’t boot. How can I fix this problem.

I also tried this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z78S.jpg

Fist time worked, and second never.

Comment: I do this all of the time. LOL. Did you check to see if you have TPM on your system? Secure Boot? That was what prevented me from doing the same thing.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  But also see this old, but still current bug for installing to external or any second drive. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 You may have to always have external plugged in, if you do not install grub to external drive.